# L2 token to ETH conversion

Tags: layer-2

From my understanding, roll up L2 tokens can be converted to ETH, but how does it work when L2 solutions can spring up limitlessly? How are L2 tokens regulated such that there won't be an unlimited supply? Each dapp could magically create ETH otherwise.

Thanks